# Does "<" satisfies strict weak ordering means that there's no need for "==" definition?

Tags: c++

I don't know much about the math behind strict weak ordering. But I've read something:

> An operator that satisfies strict weak ordering can express all other
>   logical operators
>
> ```
> <(a, b)  : (a < b)
> <=(a, b): !(b < a)
> ==(a, b): !(a < b) && !(b < a)
> !=(a, b) : (a < b) || (b < a)
> >(a, b)  : (b < a)
> >=(a, b): !(a < b)
> ```

So does it means that there's no need for "==" definition, since "<" satisfies strict weak ordering, which can express all logical operators? (This may obviously seem not correct because I've seen classes define both `<` and `==`.)

An easy to understand explanation would be also much-appreciated :D. Not necessary to be too "mathematical" or "technically right".

---

Could someone give me 1 or 2 (if they are easy to find) examples that the standard library defines other operators based on `<`? A reference to source code would be good enough.

Comment: I'd like to see someone mention partially ordered sets. This kind of thing is fascinating and a fun thought experiment. I'd also like to see someone cite the C++ standard, since this is a C++ question.

Comment: @NicHartley You can find videos about partially order on YouTube. Actually I don't want to talk too much about math in this question... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R36F8CWAi2k&t=4s

Comment: @iBug ...And? Not everyone has gone to college. Plenty of people here are high schoolers, or self-taught, and might have never encountered it.

Comment: @NicHartley I think he means that one should find a textbook to learn that. Calm down friend.

Comment: @Rick Sure, it'd be best learned in a textbook, but it's not particularly likely you'd hear about it unless it's explicitly mentioned. (Also, I wasn't mad, and re-reading my comment... doesn't really make me sound mad, sorry you read it that way, I guess?)

Comment: @NicHartley Sorry if my wording misled you. The OP seems to have correctly understood me.

Comment: @NicHartley Oh, I knew it's related to *Discrete Mathematics*. I've Googled it. Here I just want some experienced opinions or explanations about my question.

Comment: You can check an article I wrote here: [https://github.com/bashrc-real/Codearchive/blob/master/cpp/Strict_weak_ordering_and_stl.md]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing's first. Defining `operator <` doesn't mean you get a definition of `operator ==` for free from the compiler. It still needs to be defined explicitly.

The table above assumes something that is true for many types and ordering relations, but not for all. It assumes that equivalence between two elements implies equality. That need not hold.

We can certainly use `<` to check for equivalence between two elements. They are equivalent according to the strict week ordering (that's what `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` means). It doesn't necessarily mean those elements are equal.

A good example would be case insensitive comparison between strings of characters. In that case we will certainly have `!("ab" < "AB") && !("AB" < "ab")`, and the two string are equivalent, but they aren't equal in value.

Having said all that. If the order relation you defined implies all the other ones for your type, [there are tricks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Barton-Nackman_trick) to generate all the other operations from it. Just as the table demonstrates.

Comment: Very helpful (O^~^O). Btw, could you give me 1 or 2 (if they are easy to find) examples that the standard library defines other operators based on `<`?

Comment: @Rick - One example would be the soon deprecated [`std::rel_ops`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp). Everything there is according to the same principle. `std::set` also assumes it can use `<` to determine if two elements are equivalent. There's probably more I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 3):

> So does it means that there's no need for "==" definition?

You still need to define it if you want the clients of your class to use it. It can be implemented in terms of the `<` operator. It might be easier to implement `==` operator in terms of the `<` operator. However, it might be better to implement it cleanly by itself for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of Algebraic Structure, there's a kind of binary relation called "[Partially Ordered Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)". A partially ordered set is defined as a binary relation that is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

In C++, one could implement `bool operator<(a, b)` as a POS relationship operator. In this case, `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` can hardly be considered equivalent to equality. One possible implementation is testing if a node is a descendant of another node. This is a perfect example of a POS relationship.

Comment: @curiousguy Both. Depends on how you think about it.